# Parse for iOS : ACL for more than one user

Tags: ios, acl, parse-platform

Can more than one user have access to a PFObject? 
And how do I do that? 
I am on iOS, and want a PFObject to be accessible by 2 or more PFUsers.

I checked the functions:

```
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACLwithUser:somePFUser]
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

The second function is of no use for me, because that is for "all" PFObjects created on my device. However, I want to control the acl's on object by object basis. Can we do that? THanks!

I am doing this:

```
PFObject *newObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:KEY_CLASSNAME];
[newObj setACL:[PFACL ACLWithUser:some_pfUser]];
[newObj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {//handle block execution.}];
```

However, I want something like:

```
[newObj addACLForUser:[PFACL ACLWithUser:second_pfUser]]; // Something like this.

[newObj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {//handle block execution.}];
```

Can we do something like this? And if yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to people at Parse, I got to know that the ACL should be set as a JSON list of all the users who want to access the content.

Comment: Can you please provide example of that json? What is the key and value of each object?

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you need to use "Roles" as opposed to ACL.  You can set up multiple roles, (i'm pretty sure unlimited) and then add users to that role.  Then, associate the "Role" with the object and it should be good to go.

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out. Thanks! However, I asked people at Parse, and they told that the ACL should be set as a JSON list of all the users who want to access the content.

Comment: That sounds like the better option then. Exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACL];
[acl setPublicReadAccess:NO];
[acl setPublicWriteAccess:NO];
[acl setWriteAccess:YES forUser:user1];
[acl setWriteAccess:YES forUser:user2];
object.ACL = acl;
```